# Scrapy: Project can't be created

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently following the [Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html) tutorial and am at the step where there's a creation of a project, however this error is produced everytime I run the command `scrapy startproject tutorial`.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\Scripts\scrapy-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 252, in __init__
    log_scrapy_info(self.settings)
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\log.py", line 149, in log_scrapy_info
    for name, version in scrapy_components_versions()
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 35, in scrapy_components_versions
    ("pyOpenSSL", _get_openssl_version()),
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\versions.py", line 43, in _get_openssl_version
    import OpenSSL
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\crypto.py", line 16, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "C:\Users\Me\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I suspected that the issue is in my installation of Scrapy, so I tried reinstalling Scrapy(first via pip then conda) but it still doesn't fix the problem. I then tried to install the packages that Scrapy needed(one by one) but it's still not fixing anything.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to install [Win64OpenSSL_Light-1_0_2h](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) and reinstall `cryptography`?

```
pip install -I cryptography
```

See this [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35913648/python-error-when-import-openssl).